Github actions pytest FileNotFoundError
My pytests work when I run them locally, but not in github actions. I think this might be due to the module path format but I really am stumped as to why.
Here is my config:
    name: Python package
    
    on: [push, pull_request]
    
    jobs:
      build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
        steps:
        - name: Check out repository code
          uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
        - name: Set up Python
          uses: actions/setup-python@v2
          with:
            python-version: '3.9'
    
        - name: Install dependencies
          run: |
            python -m venv venv
            source venv/bin/activate
            pip install -r requirements.txt
            pip install pytest
            pip install .
    
        - name: Verify installation
          run: |
            source venv/bin/activate
            pip list
    
        - name: Debug Package Installation
          run: |
            source venv/bin/activate
            echo "Installed package files:"
            find venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ml_save_memory_flow -type f || true
    
        - name: Print Python Path
          run: |
            source venv/bin/activate
            echo "PYTHONPATH:"
            echo $PYTHONPATH
    
        - name: Run tests
          run: |
            source venv/bin/activate
            pytest ml_save_memory_flow/tests --verbose

I get the error:
 ------------------------------- Captured stdout --------------------------------
Resource gazetteer exists in package ml_save_memory_flow.ner_re.resources: False
=========================== short test summary info ============================
ERROR ml_save_memory_flow/tests/E2E_test.py - FileNotFoundError: 'gazetteer' resource not found in 'ml_save_memory_flow.ner_re.resources'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=============================== 1 error in 5.86s ===============================
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.    

However it is installed in site-packages and all paths seem correct.
venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ml_save_memory_flow/ner_re/resources/gazetteer

setup.py also incudes:
package_data={
    'ml_save_memory_flow.ner_re.resources': ['*'],
}

Is there anything else I can debug to find out why the packages are not being found?
